# Как получить разницу дат считанных из DatePicker в днях?

Tags: java, javafx, дата

Допустим есть два DatePicker'а, в одном пользователь выбирает одну дату, а в другом
другую. Как считать дату из DatePicker'ов, как найти разницу в датах (в днях.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long difference = java.sql.Date.valueOf(firstDatePicker.getValue()).getTime() - java.sql.Date.valueOf(secondDatePicker.getValue()).getTime();
int days =  (int)(difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример в секундах. Это один из энного количества.

```
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
dp.getValue();
Duration.between(dp.getValue(), LocalDate.now()).getSeconds()
```